# How to extract all work items descriptions from a project in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a project hosted in Azure DevOps and I want to extract description from all work items in it. Is there a way to generate a pdf file or something like that?

Comment: You could have a look here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/titles-ids-descriptions?view=azure-devops

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried so far? What hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try [Work Item Print](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrtarantula.wiprint) to print your work item info into pdf.

Additionally, you can try these solutions to export your work items into Word:

1. [Enhanced Export](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mskold.mskold-enhanced-export)
2. [TeamSpec](https://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teamspec/features/microsoft-word-integration.aspx)

Then save your Word file as pdf.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Azure DevOps extension in the marketplace:
[Export to Word/PDF - Azure DevOps Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Documentero.export-to-document) which does exactly what you need.

Additionally, you can use some advanced template capabilities (like conditions or changing representation depending on work item type). (Extension relies on [Documentero](https://documentero.com/))